# Serialization of MS CRM 2011 plugin execution context to JSON

Tags: c#, json, plugins, dynamics-crm-2011, json.net

I'm trying to serialize MS CRM 2011 plugin execution context to JSON to analyze it later (I need to find issue of the error, and I would prefer to have more human-readable form of context dump).

But all my tries leads to a serialization errors, like following:

`Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error getting value from 'ServiceProvider' on 'Plugin+LocalPluginContext`

Plugin was generated by Visual Studio add-on. Code was placed inside base class `Plugin`, like this:

```
internal void Trace(string message)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(message) || this.TracingService == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (this.PluginExecutionContext == null)
    {
        this.TracingService.Trace(message);
    }
    else
    {
        this.TracingService.Trace(
            "{0}, Correlation Id: {1}, Initiating User: {2}",
            message,
            this.PluginExecutionContext.CorrelationId,
            this.PluginExecutionContext.InitiatingUserId);

        var jss = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        var dcr = new DefaultContractResolver();

        dcr.DefaultMembersSearchFlags |= System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic;
        jss.ContractResolver = dcr;

        this.TracingService.Trace("Local Context Dump: {0}", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this, jss));
    }
}
```

I believe the issue is the general approach. `LocalContext` is very complex object. JSON.NET is unable to serialize some kind of types. But I cannot nail down this restriction.

Could you please help me to correct the approach?

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to get do something similar, but rather than JSON'ing it, I created by own C# method to covert it to a string, and I just add it to a log:  Here it the C# function if it helps.

```
protected String GetPluginExecutionInfo(IPluginExecutionContext context)
{
    var lines = new List<String>();
    var target = GetTarget<Entity>(context);

    lines.Add("MessageName: " + context.MessageName);
    lines.Add("PrimaryEntityName: " + context.PrimaryEntityName);
    lines.Add("PrimaryEntityId: " + context.PrimaryEntityId);
    lines.Add("BusinessUnitId: " + context.BusinessUnitId);
    lines.Add("CorrelationId: " + context.CorrelationId);
    lines.Add("Depth: " + context.Depth);
    lines.Add("Has Parent Context: " + (context.ParentContext != null));
    lines.Add("InitiatingUserId: " + context.InitiatingUserId);
    AddParameters(lines, context.InputParameters, "Input Parameters");
    lines.Add("IsInTransaction: " + context.IsInTransaction);
    lines.Add("IsolationMode: " + context.IsolationMode);
    lines.Add("Mode: " + context.Mode);
    lines.Add("OperationCreatedOn: " + context.OperationCreatedOn);
    lines.Add("OperationId: " + context.OperationId);
    lines.Add("Organization: " + context.OrganizationName + "(" + context.OrganizationId + ")");
    AddParameters(lines, context.OutputParameters, "Output Parameters");
    AddEntityReference(lines, context.OwningExtension, "OwningExtension");
    AddEntityImages(lines, context.PostEntityImages, "Post Entity Images");
    AddEntityImages(lines, context.PreEntityImages, "Pre Entity Images");
    lines.Add("SecondaryEntityName: " + context.SecondaryEntityName);
    AddParameters(lines, context.SharedVariables, "Shared Variables");
    lines.Add("Stage: " + context.Stage);
    lines.Add("UserId: " + context.UserId);

    if (target == null || target.Attributes.Count == 0)
    {
        lines.Add("Target: Empty ");
    }
    else
    {
        lines.Add("* Target " + target.ToEntityReference().GetNameId() + " *");
        lines.Add(target.ToStringAttributes("    Target[{0}]: {1}"));
    }

    lines.Add("* App Config Values *");
    foreach (var key in ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.AllKeys)
    {
        lines.Add("    [" + key + "]: " + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key]);
    }

    return String.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines);
}

private static void AddEntityReference(List<string> nameValuePairs, EntityReference entity, string name)
{
    if (entity != null)
    {
        nameValuePairs.Add(name + ": " + entity.GetNameId());
    }
}

private static void AddEntityImages(List<string> nameValuePairs, EntityImageCollection images, string name)
{
    if (images != null && images.Count > 0)
    {
        nameValuePairs.Add("** " + name + " **");
        foreach (var image in images)
        {
            if (image.Value == null || image.Value.Attributes.Count == 0)
            {
                nameValuePairs.Add("    Image[" + image.Key + "] " + image.Value + ": Empty");
            }
            else
            {
                nameValuePairs.Add("*   Image[" + image.Key + "] " + image.Value.ToEntityReference().GetNameId() + "   *
                nameValuePairs.Add(image.Value.ToStringAttributes("        Entity[{0}]: {1}"));
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        nameValuePairs.Add(name + ": Empty");
    }
}

private static void AddParameters(List<string> nameValuePairs, ParameterCollection parameters, string name)
{
    if (parameters != null && parameters.Count > 0)
    {
        nameValuePairs.Add("* " + name + " *");
        foreach (var param in parameters)
        {
            nameValuePairs.Add("    Param[" + param.Key + "]: " + param.Value);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        nameValuePairs.Add(name + ": Empty");
    }
}

public static String ToStringAttributes(this Entity entity, string attributeFormat = "[{0}]: {1}")
{
    return String.Join(Environment.NewLine, entity.Attributes.Select(att => 
        String.Format(attributeFormat, att.Key, GetAttributeValue(att.Value))));
}

private static string GetAttributeValue(object value)
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        return "Null";
    }

    var osv = value as OptionSetValue;
    if (osv != null)
    {
        return osv.Value.ToString();
    }

    var entity = value as EntityReference;
    if (entity != null)
    {
        return entity.GetNameId();
    }

    return value.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you aware of Plugin Debugger approach? Recheck [this article](http://guruprasadcrm.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-to-debug-crm-2011-online-plugin.html) that describes how to debug plugins that are located even in CRM Online.

Comment: Yes, I am, but I want to come up with more usable unit-testing approach, better than https://crm2011plugintest.codeplex.com/ one. If I succeed I will share my results on Kiev CRM UG.

Answer (score 1):

This works better for me
http://www.crmanswers.net/2015/02/json-and-crm-sandbox-plugins.html

```
string parameter1 = "";
using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Course));
    serializer.WriteObject(memoryStream, course);
    parameter1 = Encoding.Default.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: I managed to make this code work, through it required me to add `[DataContract]` attribute to the class definition and `[DataMember]` to all its public fields.